# Adding Description fields in Active Directory for Outlook Contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

there is a request to add a filed in the active directory specially the description field to
a created field in the contact card for all employees in the Address book for Exchange online & on-perms so, i was wondering how can i do that.
I have attached image for the contact card in the outlook & what i expected to do with the new field position.

[Add Field in the contact card for exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY5ec.png)

Comment: My org has attempted to do this, and it doesn't work. The Contact Card is relatively hard coded, as I understand it, and does not easily accept custom or different fields being added to it.

Comment: I believe that we can do that as there are custom field to be added even on exchange online or  on-prem that's why i need help

Comment: If there are custom fields, please show us what you have tried so far and how it has, or has not, worked out.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add some other properties to the Outlook contacts card, but "Description" field is not supported as it's not listed in the table of the article below:

[Customize the profile card in Win32 apps using registry keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-profile-card-in-win32-apps-using-registry-keys-449afd21-6e5e-4b1f-8051-6515630d7537?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)